# Using ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for big automatic insertion

Tags: mysql, sql, key, duplicates, bulkinsert

I have to insert a lot of rows to a table `basic_data` like this:

> **basic_data**
>   customer | max_sale | total_sales

```
CREATE TABLE `basic_data` (
`id`  int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`customer`  int(11) NOT NULL ,
`total_sales`  decimal(15,2) NOT NULL ,
`max_sale`  tinyint(2) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `customer` USING BTREE (`customer`)
)
```

As I get (customer, max_sale) and (customer, total_sales) in different queries, I would like to know if it is possible to fill the table so that one customer has just one row with both values `max_sale` and `total_sales`.

My insert queries are:

```
INSERT INTO 
basic_data (customer, max_sale)
SELECT a.customer, a.max_sale
FROM sales a
 ....
GROUP BY customer;


INSERT INTO
basic_data (customer,total_value)
SELECT customer, SUM(sales) total_value
FROM sales a
GROUP BY customer;
```

And I have read I can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but cannot manage to use it properly.

My attempts on

```
INSERT INTO
basic_data (customer,total_value)
SELECT customer, SUM(sales) total_value
FROM sales a
GROUP BY customer
ON DUPLICATE KEY person UPDATE total_value = ...
```

have been unsuccessful and I think it is because `ON DUPLICATE KEY` does not work with `GROUP BY`.

Any idea how to store data this way? Big thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 1**

```
INSERT INTO basic_data (customer,total_value)
SELECT customer, total_value
FROM
(
    SELECT customer, SUM(sales) total_value
    FROM   sales a
    GROUP  BY customer
) c
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total_value = c.total_value
```

Comment: Mmm doesn't seem to be working, I get a `Unknown column 'a.total_value' in 'field list'` message.

Comment: try `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total_value = SUM(sales)`

Comment: I tried and I am getting `[Err] 1111 - Invalid use of group function`

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still inserting duplicated entries : (

Comment: sorry i messed up, try to execute the query with your original schema.

Comment: It worked!!!!! Thank you so much, @JW, you are such a tireless searcher of the good answer :)